# How to resample matrices to test for the robustness of their correlation?

Tags: distributions, correlation, matrix, resampling

I have several populations where I have morphology and diet for each individual. I am interested in the correlation between diet and morphological distances. However the number of individuals in each population ranges from 22 to 80 individuals. I have looked at the correlation diet-morphology for each population and (not surprisingly) the correlation coefficientis is highly correlated with the number of individuals per population.

I would like to resample (without replacement) the populations with 60-80 individuals and get random samplings of 30 individuals (1000 times). I would like to get a correlation coefficient distribution against which to test the original value of the correlation.

I guess it is possible do this in R, however I have never written a script in R and I am not familiar with resampling techniques at all. 
Any help with coding will be greatly appreciated

Thank you
Camille

Comment: Why is it not surprising that the correlation coefficient is highly correlated with the number of individuals per population? I see no obvious reason to expect it to be.

Comment: We can answer your implicit question without any simulation: although the Pearson correlation coefficient is a biased estimator of the correlation, [the bias is usually small](http://www.uv.es/revispsi/articulos1.03/9.ZUMBO.pdf), so the center of the sampling distribution you propose will be close to the correlation coefficient of the data from which you are sampling.

Answer (score 2):

It would help if you could address @onestop's question, and I also agree with @whuber that using the correlation's you've found are probably fine.  But I will try to provide some help with your question. Usually, when we resample, we do so *with* replacement, and we take a bootsample of the *same size* as the original sample.  That is, if your sample is size 80, we resample with replacement to get 80 bootobservations in our bootsample (which will include some duplicates).

There are [at least](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/bootstrap/index.html) two [packages](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/boot/index.html) in R that do bootstrapping, but I usually just do it myself.  It's not that much more code and I like setting it up according to my specifications.  Let's say that your data are in a matrix with 2 columns and 80 rows.  You can bootstrap a correlation by sampling rows with replacement, calculating the correlation and storing it.  Here's some sample R code:

```r
set.seed(1)                            # this is for reproducability
X        = matrix(rnorm(160), ncol=2)  # a generic matix, note that I made no effort 
                                       # to correlate the data, this is just an example
rows     = c(1:80)                     # row numbers to resample over
bootDist = c()                         # a vector to store the output

for(i in 1:1000) {                                 # used a for loop, but it took 1 sec
  bootRows = sample(rows, size=80, replace=T)      # this gives me the rows I will use
  bootDist[i] = cor(X[bootRows,1], X[bootRows,2])  # the cor for that bootsample
}

summary(bootDist)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
-0.5573 -0.3765 -0.2997 -0.2916 -0.2128  0.2336
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It was very helpful. I use the following code:                                               rows = c(1:2346)
bootDist = c()  
for(i in 1:1000) {        
  bootRows = sample(rows, size=435, replace=F) 
  bootDist[i] = cor(tjornres[bootRows,1], tjornres[bootRows,2])
}
summary(bootDist)                                     hist(bootDist,)                                                         I hope this script will help other student.